# Hover on Links in Footer not Working

Tags: css, hover, hyperlink

I am unable to get :hover to function on my footer links.  Does this have to do with z-index?

Thank you!

URL: http://bonusest.com/clients/republican_committee/

Comment: You should set up a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your main div with id `page-wrap` is ontop (overlapping) of your footer so the links in the footer cannot be clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I just tried totally removing that #page-wrap div (warning: page structure is a little funky now) and it still doesn't work.  Same link as before - http://bonusest.com/clients/republican_committee/

Answer (score 0):

Seems the .links and .contact divs don't contain any actual links - you need to wrap them in anchor tags like in your main navigation.

As for the .social div, this should work:

```
<h4>Find Us</h4>
<ul>
    <li id="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li id="twitter"><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
    <li id="picassa"><a href="#">picassa</a></li>       
</ul>
```

You'll want to keep the text-indent:-9999px to hide the text. To add a hover state, simply target #facebook:hover

Comment: I'm mainly focusing on the .social div - the rest is just filler.  I removed the -9999 text indent as well as the text - but it still doesn't work.  Ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again for your response.  Somehow it's still not working though. I went ahead and threw some anchor tags around the text in the .links div, but nothing there either.  I'm completely befuddled.  Here is the link again - http://www.bonusest.com/clients/republican_committee

Comment: checked your site again, and didn't see the ul list under the .social div, so can't really help trouble shoot that. as for the .links div, adding `<a>` won't make it a link, you need to set a parameter such as `<a href="#">` for it to show up as a link in your browser